# What is the git equivalent to hg update to get a specific historical version?

Tags: git

I thought it was `git reset --hard` but in addition to reverting to an old version that deleted all my local changes since I had last pushed to the server! Now I have to redo an hour's worth of work... thank God I pushed last night or I'd be screwed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git checkout -b new_branch_name your_commit_hash`.

If you don't use `-b new_branch_name` it will end up in a detached HEAD state.

Comment: Why would I want to create a new branch? I just want to load up an old version of the code to compare how it behaves with the latest version; I don't intend to make additional changes. BTW I found an article which told me how to recover from a `git reset` - I had to use `git reflog` to find the latest "good" commit (it's not actually deleted!) and then `git reset` to that particular commit ID and now everything is back! :D

Comment: yes then simply ignore the -b flag and use `git checkout your_commit_hash`